# Regex for .less extension file that excludes .module.less

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to create a regex that will match strings ending with `.less` but not ending with `.module.less`.

For now i could express the not ending with `.module.less` with this regex `/^(?!.*[.]module[.]less$)/`.

I'm using **JavaScript** as a language. How can i do that?

## What i want

- "style.module.less"
- "style.less" ✅
- "index.js"

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/^(?!.*\.module\.less$).*\.less$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lookahead regex only prevents matching strings ending with `.module.less`.

You may add `.*\.less$` to the consuming part:

```
/^(?!.*\.module\.less$).*\.less$/
                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

[It will only match strings ending with `.less` now](https://regex101.com/r/PjstEc/1).

The `.*` pattern will greedily match the whole string and `\.less$` will match `.less` (`\.less`) at the end of the string (`$`).